# javascript function invocation in object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object like the following:

```
'use strict';

function Queue() {

   this.newJob = function(parm1, callback){
       if ( parm1 == 'example')
           newJob('name');
       else
           ....
   }

}

module.exports = Queue;
```

inside this.newJob function I am calling newJob again. like so:

```
newJob('name');
```

I keep getting the error:

```
ReferenceError: newJob is not defined
```

How can I call the function without getting the error?

When I change `newJob` to `this.newJob` I get that `TypeError: this.newJob is not a function`

Comment: You're going to need to add more code for us to be able to analyze. include the variable newDataAnalysisJob.

Comment: no enough description of the problem

Comment: I meant newJob. Not a variable. Just edited the question.

Comment: "When I change newJob to this.newJob I get that TypeError: this.newJob is not a function" — There's a live demo in my answer. It shows that that doesn't happen with that code. You need to provide a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a variable called `newJob` and assign a reference to the function to it.

Since you said you were calling it from within the `newJob` function, the easiest way would be to create it using a **named** function expression.

```js
function Queue() {
   this.newJob = function newJob(parm1, callback){
       console.log(parm1);
       if (parm1 == "example") {
          newJob('name');
       }

   }
}

var q = new Queue;
q.newJob("example");
```

Alternatively, you could reference the instance you called the function on in the first place:

```js
function Queue() {
   this.newJob = function (parm1, callback){
       console.log(parm1);
       if (parm1 == "example") {
          this.newJob('name');
       }

   }
}

var q = new Queue;
q.newJob("example");
```

Comment: If i do this.newJob i get: TypeError: this.newJob is not a function

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins — You're doing it wrong. It works in the example I provided. You haven't provided a [mcve]. There is no way I can tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Paul — It's a live demo. You can click "Run code snippet" and see it working! `this` is the Queue instance. When you call `x.foo` the value of `this` is `x` not `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

To invoke `this.newJob` inside an instance of your Queue, you need to always say `this.newJob`, rather than just `newJob`.

Also, it takes less memory to attach the function to the prototype, like so:

```
function Queue() {

}

Queue.prototype.newJob = function(parm1, callback){
  if(someVariableThatPreventsInfiniteRecursion === false)
    this.newJob()// whatever.  
}
```

Comment: Danger! Infinite recursion!

Comment: lol, sure, that's a problem with his question in general. I'll update with an if statement.